select column 'name' or 'nm' from table 'tb2' only 1 column will exist at a time either 'name' or 'nm'
in amazon redshift table i need to select column from table tb2
following conditions:

table refresh everyday so it will either have column 'name' or 'nm'
if name is present then value of name should be there
if nm is present then value of nm should be there
both column will not exist together in any condition

pg_get_late_data_columns and information schema not working for me

Both columns are in the table, but only one will have a value? then you want coalesce(name, nm). If only one of the columns exists at all, then when the table refreshes each day you have a broken ETL process doing that work.

This will need to be some form of dynamic SQL.  You should be able to get the info you need in pg_table_def - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_PG_TABLE_DEF.html
